# Solving recurrence equations with fractions using Recursion Tree Method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, recurrence

I'm trying to figure out how to solve recurrence equations, and I can do them easily using the recursion tree method if the equation is something like this, for example:

```
T(1) = 1;
T(n) = n + 2T(n/2) for n > 1
```

But I'm having trouble understanding how to solve equations for which the recurrence is modified by a fraction, like this for example:

```
T(1) = 1;
T(n) = n + 3/2T(.9n) for n > 1
```

How can there be 3/2th of a branch in a tree? Is it impossible to solve this using recursion trees? Can anyone explain exactly how this would work in the recursion tree method? Or is there another method that would be easier for this form of equation?

Comment: masters theorem can be handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can there be `3/2 th` of a branch?

Easy: you have 4 branches on a step `x`, then on a step `x + 1` you will have `4 * 3 / 2 = 6` branches (if you can't divide the numbers, use floor).

> Can anyone explain exactly how this would work in the recursion tree
>   method?

You unroll the recursion, create a huge sum, spot the similarity and converge the sum.

> Is there another method that would be easier for this form of equation?

Yes, people have done what I described in the previous step for a general recursion [T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n) and created a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form). All you need is to remember it (actually you need to understand it) and you can solve any sort of this recursions.